# How to stretch a background in the 960 grid system?

Tags: css

Basically the problem I am having is I set a background color to the div's but there is white spacing on the top left and right sides. The question is how do I correctly remove these white spaces? Here is my code (I am using the 960 grid system):

```
   <div id="logo">
    <div class="container_12">
        <div class="grid_12">
            Header and logo
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<div id="main">
    <div class="container_12">
        <div class="grid_12">
            <div class="grid_6 alpha">Header text</div>
            <div class="grid_1"></div>
            <div class="grid_5 omega">Button</div>
        </div>
    </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

And my css is:

```
div#logo {
height: 175px;
background-color: #083d5e;

}

div#main {
height: 205px;
background-color: #01070b;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: submit your code on http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: There's probably a padding on the parent or something.

Answer (score 0):

The 960 grid system is for make a structure of the design, so the div elements that you want to follow this structure needs to be inside.

```
<div class="container_12">
    <div class="grid_12">
       <div id="logo">
        Header and logo
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Right but then the background would not stretch because it would only stay 960px wide.

Comment: as @SVS mentioned before upload the code to http://jsfiddle.net/ to understand or upload some screenshots

Comment: Here you go http://jsfiddle.net/pAvgx/ but the problem is not displayed in the jsfiddle, but with chrome and firefox it's like basically a border on top, left, and right side of the div's. Of course it's not an actual border but it's like there is one, I tried doing margins, and width 100% but it's not helping.

Comment: I took a look at what you posted, from that jsfiddle link and the problem still persists with your code as well. Basically the background is not reach the top, left, and right side of the pages, they just remain white.

Comment: Have you tried to reset the css? , there are some default styles used by the browsers

Comment: How do I go about reseting the css?

Comment: the http://960.gs/ grid system includes a file called reset.css that you should include . This file reset all the default css values that are used by the browsers